# Is there a way to stop powershell core from using its own colors in the VSCode terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

Is there a way to stop powershell core from using its own colors? When I open a new powershell core terminal in VSCode the default colors are used, but when I start typing commands powershell core seems to use its own colors.

[image: pwsh commands have their own colors]

Does anyone know if powershell core can be used without it bringing in its own colors?

Thanks!

Edit: after customizing the colors in the manner proposed by Redline, it now looks the way I was hoping - thanks Redline!:

[image: settings.json]

[image: terminal override colors being used!]

Comment: [This](https://dev.to/sfarias051/how-to-change-the-terminal-style-in-vscode-in-an-easy-way-5139) might work

Comment: Okay upon further inspection, Redline has indeed provided the correct answer - I simply needed to override the "terminal.background" and "terminal.ansiBlue" settings in the vscode appsettings.json file, for the color scheme I wanted to use - sincerest thanks Redline!